# Morse Decoder program keep giving unwanted [ instead of English. Why?

Tags: c++

I was trying to decode morse code as an assignment, but I somehow am stuck on how this output is always `[` instead of the English wordings.

Here are some of the test cases:

Test 1

- Input: `._.|.._|_.`
- Output: `RUN`

Test 2

- Input: `_|....|..|...||..|...||_|....|.||.__|._|_.__`
- Output: `THIS IS THE WAY`

Test 3

- Input: `...|....|._|_.|_|._|._.|._|__`
- Output: `SHANTARAM`

Test 4

- Input: `.__.|.|___|.__.|._..|.||..|_.||_|....|.|..|._.||._.|..|__.|....|_||__|..|_.|_..|...||_.|.|..._|.|._.||_|._|_._|.||.__.|._.|..|_..|.||..|_.||_|....|.|..|._.||_|._|._..|.|_.|_|...`
- Output: `PEOPLE IN THEIR RIGHT MINDS NEVER TAKE PRIDE IN THEIR TALENTS`

Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

/**
 * A morse code decoder.
 */

using namespace std;

// IMPORTANT:  Do NOT change any of the function headers
//             It means that you will need to use the function headers as is
//             You may add other functions wherever appropriate

/**
 * Decode the morse code `s` and return the text character
 */
string morseCodeToText(string s)
{
    string text = "";
    string currentLetter = "";

    string const morsecode[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.",                  //array of alphabet equivalent morse codes
    "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
    ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};

    istringstream ss(s);

    size_t const characters = 26;

    while(ss >> currentLetter)
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        while(currentLetter != morsecode[index] && index < characters)
        {
            ++index;                         //increment here so we don't have to decrement after the loop like if we put in the condition
        }

        text += 'A' + index;
    }

    return text;
}


int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << morseCodeToText(s) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the provided examples show no signs of this mysterious `[`. This makes the question more confusing than necessary.

Comment: Yea I just don't know what to do

Comment: It looks like you are using "`|`" as a delimiter in your example text, but I see no sign of that delimiter in your code.

Comment: @jjramsey Is it possible to explain how | is a delimiter I'm not so sure

Comment: Umm what do you mean by rubber duck? Do I run a debugger?

Comment: The `[` character comes immediately after `Z` in the ASCII table. Your `while(currentLetter...` loop never finds a match (because the *entire* input string is compared), so that character is appended to the answer. You need to replace your `|` with spaces.

Comment: Debugger is a great start. With a debugger you can see exactly what the program is doing with your code at each "step" of the program. For example, you can watch `while(currentLetter != morsecode[index] && index < characters)` closely and see what values are being compared. You'll also find that `currentLetter != morsecode[index]` is executed before `index < characters`, allowing the program to go out of bounds, the non-existent `morsecode[26]` is accessed, when no match is found.

Comment: Replace `ss >> currentLetter` with `getline(ss, currentLetter, '|')`

Comment: Hint: After you do `ss >> currentLetter`, what does the variable `currentLetter` hold?

Comment: ss >> currentLetter just replaces ss

Comment: In your example input, you have things like `._.` with an underscore representing a dash. In your source code, you use `-` a hyphen to represent a dash. You'll need to make sure that these line up.

Comment: "Is it possible to explain how | is a delimiter?" In your example text, "`|`" is used to separate the Morse code representations of letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ss >> currentLetter)
```

Here you're reading your input until a newline is found. You want to read until a `|` is meet.

For that, you can simply rely on [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (see `delim`):

```
while(std::getline(ss, currentLetter, '|'))
```

---

Why `[` though?

```
currentLetter != morsecode[index]
```

You're comparison is always false. This makes index be 26 when the inner while loop ends. This leads to:

```
text += 'A' + index; // 65 + 26 = 91 '['
```

test being always one-past-Z, which is `[` in ASCII.

Comment: Your new while loop gives an error that results in ->->->

Comment: Is it possible to point out how ->->-> results as well? Thanks